# I need Present modal view controller animate from left to right like drawer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need Present modal view controller animate from left to right like
  drawer?

My code:-

```
 MenuViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewStory"]; 
 vc.delegate= self;
 CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation]; 
 transition.duration = 0.6;
 transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; 
 transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
 transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
 [vc.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil]; 
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Share with us what you tried please

Comment: MenuViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewStory"];
    vc.delegate= self;
    

        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    
        transition.duration = 0.6;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [vc.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there, not in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can use below method while pushing a controller in navigation controller with animated **NO**

```
- (void)animateControllerFromLeftToRight
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setDuration:0.65f];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.navigationController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"AnimationFromLeftToRight"];
}
```